# Handling Error After Sending Data to Client in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, http, fastapi

I am trying to decide how to approach this issue.
Basically, a client can request data from a GET request and the server then fetches the records and return the data to the client. However, the server also updates the `status` column of the returned records in a postgres database before sending the data, as a result, the client will not be able to request the same data again.

But lets say there might be a case where the client requested the data and the status of the records were updated, but the client did not receive it due to some error in connection. In this case I want to rollback the database change made so the client can request the data again.

In FastAPI how can I know whether the data sent was successfully received by the client. Any other suggestion you can give to solve this problem?

Currently I am using Background Task object, which will make the update after the response has been sent. However, upon further inspection I realised even if the data does not get sent successfully it will still run the function which updates the status.